# How to post to php on input change then get results in content div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do just what the title says, when data is inputted into the textfield, I want it sent to posttothis.php, then have the result printed in a content div. I can't seem to make it work.

testscript.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("\<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<div id="content" name="content">
<script>
$('#text').keyup(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "posttothis.php",
    data: {text: $(this).val()},
    success: function(data)
            {
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

posttothis.php

```
<?php
$testvar=$_POST['text'];
echo $testvar;
?>
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** Updated my script with the suggested modifications, but still can't get it to display what I type in the textbox in the content div. To answer the questions below: I don't want to submit the form, I just want to get the value from it on every change. Console shows no errors.

**EDIT2:** I updated the working code, maybe it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: how u posting values from "testscript.html" without "form tag"?

Comment: what does your Javascript console (dev tools, Firebug etc) tell you?

Comment: you're missing a comma after the data property

Comment: try `alert(data)` in success:function and see data is fetch or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [On Key up](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) function instead.

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<div id="content" name="content">
<script>
$('#text').keyup(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "posttothis.php",
    data: {text: $(this).val()},
    success: function(data)
            {
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

Example

```
   <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    <div id="content" name="content">
    <script>
    $('#text').keyup(function(){
        $.post('posttothis.php', {text:$('#text').val()}, function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your data parameter is insufficient ... it should be like `{"text": $('#text').val()}` or just `"text=" + $('#text').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#text').keyup(function(){
```

Instead of

```
$('#text').change(function(){
```

Also your are missing a comma (,) after data property

```
data: {text: $('#text').val()},
```

Answer (score 0):

put **","** after data: {text: $('#text').val()}

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<div id="content" name="content">
<script>
$('#text').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "posttothis.php",
        data: {text: $('#text').val()},
        success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                }
        });
});
</script>
```